# Changed browser settings without permission

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, malware

Something very weird just happened to me. I opened up my computer and went to get on the Firefox (my primary browser) and it asked me to enable all my extensions again. After I did that, it had my home page open which was set to yahoo instead of the normal new tab page which I had it set to before. Also all the settings were reset to default. The same thing happened on google chrome. My home page was yahoo and the search bar at the top automatically searched yahoo. Opera and Microsoft edge were running like normal.

Here's where it gets weird. The problem continued into a fresh install (uninstalled both and used Opera to grab new installers off the official website so I didn't have to update my old installers).

There are three things that I think may have caused it.

1. I did the windows 10 update that came out Monday (I would have thought that would at least change everything to Bing)
2. I installed a game called space engine from what should have been a reputable site through a torrent (an official torrent not a pirated copy)
3. I updated Vuze Leap (my torrent client) just before the download.

Normally I would have used just a normal download for the game, but it was a gig so I opted for a faster download through the torrent, which was hosted on the official site.

Does anyone know what could have caused this and if my computer is still in danger. I had a the privacy safeguard virus in the past on an old computer through chrome and that was a serious pain to get rid of.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I did run Spybot Search and Destroy after and all it came up with was some browser cookies (like normal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adware**

Yahoo is a legitimate search engine, but for some reason, some groups are forcing you to install it as your default search engine. You have no choice but redo all your settings and also look out for ***Yahoo! Powered Search*** in Control Panel. Try paying closer attention the next time you see small check boxes during installation or upgrade of anything.

This is a common problem, try searching for it too.